# I have made a script that uses selenium in python3 to send messages but it doesn't work

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-3.6

This is my script (https://pastebin.com/dWLFvirn). I have used terminal to run the script but it shows error. Here is the screenshot(https://ibb.co/NSfLgL8)

I want to use "https://getlinks.info/slam-book/p/Shubha" as the link on which it has to work.

The system configuration I have is =>> 
1. Kali Linux 2020.1b 32-Bit , 
2. Python 3.7.5

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import hashlib
import string
import random

driver_location = "/home/kali/Desktop/geckodriver"

print('''\033[34m Starting Attack \033[34m''')

for i in range(10):


    driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_location)
    driver.get("https://getlinks.info/slam-book/p/Shubha")

    driver.implicitly_wait(60)

    firstbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/center/a[1]')
    firstbtn.click()

    firsttxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nametb"]')
    firsttxtbx.send_keys('I am Blackghost')

    scndbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/center/a')
    scndbtn.click()

    secondtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ0"]')
    secondtxtbx.send_keys('I have told you not to indulge in this websites')

    thdbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[1]/a')
    thdbtn.click()

    thirdtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ1"]')
    thirdtxtbx.send_keys('This websites allow multiple entry flaw.')

    frthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[2]/a')
    frthbtn.click()

    fourthtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ2"]')
    fourthtxtbx.send_keys('Which is actually a vulnability')

    fthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[3]/a')
    fthbtn.click()

    fifthtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ3"]')
    fifthtxtbx.send_keys('You must not use these types of websites.')

    sixthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[4]/a')
    sixthbtn.click()

    sixthtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ4"]')
    sixthtxtbx.send_keys('And don\'nt ever share this types of links in any social medias. ')

    svnthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[5]/a')
    svnthbtn.click()

    seventhtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ5"]')
    seventhtxtbx.send_keys('Specially in Whatsapp')

    eighthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[6]/a')
    eighthbtn.click()

    eighthtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ6"]')
    eighthtxtbx.send_keys('We are Anonymous. We are legion.')

    nthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[7]/a')
    nthbtn.click()

    ninethtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ7"]')
    ninethtxtbx.send_keys('We donot forget. We donot forgive.')

    tnthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[8]/a')
    tnthbtn.click()

    tenthtxtbx = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ipQ8"]')
    tenthtxtbx.send_keys('You must have to give these warnings in whatsapp status.')

    elvnthbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/center/div/div[9]/a')
    elvnthbtn.click()

    send_finish = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/button[1]')
    send_finish.click()

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

    print('Attack finished',i)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  tried your code using chrome browser and hopefully it will work on firefox too. To address the issue you have to induce WebDriverWait for the element to be clickable before sending key to your input.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()


    driver.get("https://getlinks.info/slam-book/p/Shubha")
    main_window = driver.current_window_handle
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium animated infinite pulse']"))).click()

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "nametb"))).send_keys('I am Blackghost')
```

[image]

**updateed solution :**

```
driver.get("https://getlinks.info/slam-book/p/Shubha")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium animated infinite pulse']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "nametb"))).send_keys('I am Blackghost')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ0']"))).send_keys('I have told you not to indulge in this websites')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ0']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ1']"))).send_keys('This websites allow multiple entry flaw.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ1']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ2']"))).send_keys('Which is actually a vulnability')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ2']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ3']"))).send_keys('You must not use these types of websites.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ3']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ4']"))).send_keys('And don\'nt ever share this types of links in any social medias.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ4']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ5']"))).send_keys('Specially in Whatsapp')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ5']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ6']"))).send_keys('We are Anonymous. We are legion.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ6']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ7']"))).send_keys('We donot forget. We donot forgive.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='divQ7']//a[contains(@class,'button no-border-radius is-fullwidth is-medium')][contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ipQ8']"))).send_keys('You must have to give these warnings in whatsapp status.')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Finish')]"))).click()
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot its throwing elementnotinteractable exception while dealing with nametb element.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Yeah you are right it must be clicked to type the string.

Comment: It does work for 'I am blackghost' , but it got stucked in the next text box after clicking the button.

Comment: Cant you amend your script accordinly ? i think your issue is resolved now